# make test Qt test case - duplicated symbol

Tags: qt, testcase

While following [test case example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html), I stuck at making.

My procedure is as below.

1. `~/Qt/5.12.2/clang_64/bin/qmake -project "QT +=testlib"`
   => it generated Testcase.pro
2. `~/Qt/5.12.2/clang_64/bin/qmake`
   => Makefile was generated
3. `~/Qt/5.12.2/clang_64/bin/moc -o testqstring.moc testqstring.h`
   => testqstring.moc was generated
4. `make`
   => moc_predefs.h and moc_testqstring.cpp were generated, and print error as below.

```
❯ make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names  -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/../Frameworks -Wl,-rpath,/Users/sungyong/Qt/5.12.2/clang_64/lib -o Testcase.app/Contents/MacOS/Testcase testqstring.o moc_testqstring.o   -F/Users/sungyong/Qt/5.12.2/clang_64/lib -framework QtGui -framework QtTest -framework Security -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL
duplicate symbol __ZN11TestQString18qt_static_metacallEP7QObjectN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv in:
    testqstring.o
    moc_testqstring.o
duplicate symbol __ZN11TestQString11qt_metacallEN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv in:
    testqstring.o
    moc_testqstring.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK11TestQString10metaObjectEv in:
    testqstring.o
    moc_testqstring.o
duplicate symbol __ZTV11TestQString in:
    testqstring.o
    moc_testqstring.o
duplicate symbol __ZTS11TestQString in:
    testqstring.o
    moc_testqstring.o
duplicate symbol __ZTI11TestQString in:
    testqstring.o
    moc_testqstring.o
duplicate symbol __ZN11TestQString11qt_metacastEPKc in:
    testqstring.o
    moc_testqstring.o
duplicate symbol __ZN11TestQString16staticMetaObjectE in:
    testqstring.o
    moc_testqstring.o
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Testcase.app/Contents/MacOS/Testcase] Error 1
```

What did I mistake?

Comment: why `~/Qt/5.12.2/clang_64/bin/qmake -project "QT +=testlib"`? if that project already has a .pro

Comment: Before `qmake -project ..`, project hadn't .pro.  I just followed Qt's test case tutorial.

Comment: In the last part of the tutorial there are 2 links:
-  tutorial1/testqstring.cpp
-  tutorial1/tutorial1.pro

Comment: I'm not fully understand what you meant.  From `Assuming that our test was saved as testqstring.cpp in an empty directory, we build the test using qmake to create a project and generate a makefile.`  .pro might generated by `qmake -project`

Comment: see https://i.imgur.com/F9fG9NM.png